# shell script to calculate completion time of parallel jobs

Tags: shell

I have a program where two processes are running parallel as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /bin/bash -s <<< "hive -f ./create.hql >&/dev/null" &
pid_c=$!
nohup /bin/bash -s <<< "hive -f ./load.hql >&/dev/null" &
pid_l=$!
wait $pid_c
ex_pid_c=$?
##time1=$(ps -p "$pid_c" -o etime=) not working
if [ $ex_pid_c -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Job completed."
else
echo "Failed"
fi
wait $pid_l
ex_pid_l=$?
##time2=$(ps -p "$pid_l" -o etime=) not working
if [ $ex_pid_l -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Job completed."
else
echo "Failed"
fi
```

Now I want to calculate the completion time of each job. How should I proceed?

Comment: I may be too picky but you want to _measure_, not _calculate_.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `time` command to know how long it took for each one (result goes to `stderr`):

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /bin/bash -s <<< "time sleep 10 >&/dev/null" &
pid_c=$!
nohup /bin/bash -s <<< "time sleep 1 >&/dev/null" &
pid_l=$!
wait $pid_c
ex_pid_c=$?
##time1=$(ps -p "$pid_c" -o etime=) not working
if [ $ex_pid_c -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Job completed."
else
  echo "Failed"
fi
wait $pid_l
ex_pid_l=$?
##time2=$(ps -p "$pid_l" -o etime=) not working
if [ $ex_pid_l -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Job completed."
else
  echo "Failed"
fi
```

Then `nohup.out` should contain the execution times like below:

```
jbo@gvavl1030010:~
$ ./a.sh
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
Job completed.
Job completed.
jbo@gvavl1030010:~
$ cat nohup.out


real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s

real    0m10.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

hope it helps

Or the easiest way is to call your shell, say `a.sh`, this way:

```
time ./a.sh
```

giving

```
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
Job completed.
Job completed.

real    0m10.01s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.01s
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to stores those times in some variable in the script then how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` command.This can be useful:-

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively

Comment: `/usr/bin/time` can also be used.  I find this useful when timing the same process on different systems (Darwin, CentOS, Ubuntu, AIX, etc) where the shell utility `time` sometimes outputs in different formats.